# I wrote an EA using a custom indicator in ex4

Tags: mql4

I wrote an EA using a custom indicator in ex4 format, everything is working. but I notice that after the strategy tester finished back testing, the screen will be white with many lines, as a result I can't see the chart, I will like to analyse if the trade is executed according to the code.

Comment: are these lines appear as a result of the indicator?

Comment: yes, it load like up to 100 of same indicator to chart instead of one and as a result what i see on the chart is uncountable lines. if i use custom indicator that is in mq4  format it only only load once to the chart, and that is exactly what i want. Could it be that the indicator i used was in ex4 format or what?

Comment: try using `HideTestIndicators()`